# Soap request body using 'postman' chrome app

Tags: web-services, google-chrome, web

How would the body of a soap request look like for the 'holiday web service' (http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl) using the Postman google app?

I'm trying to use the getHolidaysAvailable method. I have tried the suggested format found on the holidaywebservice.com site but it does not work. In short, can anyone successfully post to this web service using Postman and share the soap request headers and body you use. Thanks!

Comment: For people catch on [Law of instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument). Take a look on [Wizdler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wizdler/oebpmncolmhiapingjaagmapififiakb)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Method** needs to be POST and use http://www.holidaywebservice.com//HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl as the **URL**.

You must include the following in the **Headers**:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

You can add SOAPAction in the headers but is not necessary for this web service request to work as the request body will specify which SOAP Method to use, 'GetHolidaysAvailable'.

```
SOAPAction: "http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/GetHolidaysAvailable"
```

Finally, the **Body** should look like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns1:GetHolidaysAvailable>
     <ns1:countryCode>UnitedStates</ns1:countryCode>
   </ns1:GetHolidaysAvailable>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: How should I call a function with more than one input parameter. I tried a one and it gave me a 500 error saying `Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header... myFunctionName`

Comment: I did not find your 2nd point to be true when interacting with a WCF service. SoapUI worked properly out of the box but postman triggered complaints about an empty Action - I had to add the header.

Comment: SOAPAction in the headers but is not necessary <--- **Actually it is necessary**

Answer (score 1):

Your request could be something like this even:

```
POST /HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx/GetHolidaysAvailable HTTP/1.1    
Host: www.holidaywebservice.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

countryCode=UnitedStates
```