# Replicating Postman 'POST' method in a Cloudant db

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, cloudant

What would be the best way to get data from say:

http://www.holidaywebservice.com//HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl

and write the data into a Cloudant db? I'm able to get the 'POST' to work in Postman as per [Soap request body using 'postman' chrome app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884183/soap-request-body-using-postman-chrome-app), but I want to replicate this in Cloudant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, Cloudant is a JSON datastore and you want to send it XML?

Comment: Thanks rhyshort,

I've managed to setup the API within Bluemix using API Connect. I'm now essentially trying to write the results of this API call to any db/datastore like Cloudant in Bluemix. It is perfectly fine if I send it JSON rather than XML. Any idea if this additional step is possible?

Comment: If you convert it to json you should be able to POST it to `/$db/$docID` or to `/$db/` to create a document in the database.